# Characterization of stalk functors on category of sheaves over a space, and over a locale

Tags: sheaf-theory, locales

Let $X$ be a topological space (somewhat abusively also let it denote the category of open sets in $X$) and $\mathsf{Set}_X$ the category of $\mathsf{Set}$-valued sheaves over $X$. Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be sheaves on $X$ and suppose $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ is a map of sheaves. Then there is an induced map $\varphi_p:\mathcal{F}_p\rightarrow\mathcal{G}_p$ on stalks, where $\mathcal{F}_p=\varinjlim\mathcal{F}(U)$, ranging over $U\ni p$, given by the universal property of the colimit (explicitly $\varphi_p(U,s)\mapsto(U,\varphi_U(s))$). In other words, each $p\in X$ yields a functor $\mathsf{Set}_X\rightarrow\mathsf{Set}$ which takes the stalk at $p$.

Stalks seem to be quite important in the study of sheaves and their applications. I'm wondering if there's an equivalent definition for stalks of a sheaf over a locale $X$. I suppose one could start by considering points of a locale, namely maps $*\rightarrow X$ from the two-element locale. Since this is really a map between frames in the opposite direction, we can take the colimit of the $\mathcal{F}(U)$ ranging over the preimage of the top element in the two-element frame.

Is there any way to tell when a functor $\mathsf{Set}_X\rightarrow\mathsf{Set}$ for $X$ a topological space arose from a point $p\in X$ (up to isomorphism)? If the definition for a stalk of a sheaf over a locale I have given is "the correct one", can we similarly characterize the functors which arise from stalks when $X$ is a locale?

I suspect the nlab page on [points of topoi](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/point+of+a+topos) is related to what I'm talking about but I really don't know anything about topoi/Grothendieck topoi or geometric morphisms, so hopefully there is a more elementary explanation (especially since I am not asking about topoi in general).

Comment: Stalk functors are the ones that preserve finite limits and all colimits. That’s all there is to the topos-theoretic definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin Are there functors $\mathsf{Set}_X\rightarrow\mathsf{Set}$ which preserve finite limits and all colimits which are not stalk functors?

Comment: All such functors are stalk functors, if $X$ is sober.

Comment: @ZhenLin I can show stalk functors preserve colimits, but I’m not sure how to show stalk functors preserve finite limits. And I’ve no clue how to prove every functor which preserves colimits and finite limits is a stalk functor for sober spaces, but I’d like to figure it out - could you give me a hint? I’m new to sheaves, so probably I’m just missing some well-known result.

Comment: Yes, these are well-known results ... in topos theory. If you are interested perhaps you could start learning the subject.